# How to edit Joomla article layout/style?

Tags: joomla, joomla-article

I'm trying to edit the default articles' HTML. Right now the titles are in h2s and I want to change them to h1s and get rid of the print options etc.

There has to be some where you can edit the HTML of default article templates. Anybody know where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i know when you are posting some article on joomla you have an option to post the data as `HTML` and i don't think so that you have to change some php codes.

on the other hand when you are Adding an article that time follow these steps:

1. Click on the Parameter(Advanced) on the right side of the article
2. Select `No` of the Show Title option
3. Select `Hide` all between Article Rating to Email Icon

after all these setting you just only get your own `HTML` codes that you posted on that article as well the `<h1>` tag

**EDIT:** Or if you want to completely change the Article layout then
find the location `joomla/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php`

The above `default.php` file keeps all the layout of the article section and all the data that data that will keep on the `RightColumn`.

Comment: Strongly advise NOT to edit that file in place - as soon as you upgrade Joomla your edits will be overwritten. Copy that file to /templates/your-template/html/com_content/article/default.php (replace 'your-template' with the actual folder name of your site's template) and make your edits to this file. These will then survive the upgrade procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Changing joomla/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php is not a good idea, since all changes will be lost after your next update.

Copy the before mentioned file and place it into the Your_template/html/com_content/article folder, which would have to be created first, if its not there already.